# Implementing a generic class based on another generic class in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, class, generics, interface

I have the following interfaces and classes in TypeScript:

```
export interface PageInterface<T> {
    count: number;
    previous: string;
    next: string;
    results: T[];
}

export class Page<T> implements PageInterface<T> {}

----------------------------------------------------------

export interface AdapterInterface<T> {
    adapt(item: any): T;
}
```

And I need to implement `PageAdapter<Page<T>>`.

Is it possible? I've tried the following but ended up with errors (*Type 'Page' si not generic*):

```
export class PageAdapter<Page> implements AdapterInterface<Page> {
    adapt(item: any): Page<T> {
        return new Page<T>(item['count'], item['previous'], item['next'], item['results']);
    }
}
```

If I put `Page<T>` instead of `Page` in the first line, it doesn't work at all.

How can i implement this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you're looking for something like this:

```
export class PageAdapter<T> implements AdapterInterface<Page<T>> {
    adapt(item: any): Page<T> {
        return new Page<T>(item['count'], item['previous'], item['next'], item['results']);
    }
}
```

So, for example, a `PageAdapter<string>` can be used as an `AdapterInterface<Page<string>>`.  If you really need the generic type parameter to be a `Page`-like type, you can write something like this:

```
export class PageAdapter2<P extends Page<any>> implements AdapterInterface<P> {
    adapt(item: any): P {
        return new Page(item['count'], item['previous'], item['next'], item['results']) as P;
    }
}
```

Here, a `PageAdapter<Page<string>>` can be used as an `AdapterInterface<Page<string>>`.  The typings for this version are not as clean, however, and require [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to implement.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBUwHNgBJFNLXAHgBUA+OAbwFgAoOTubCAVxQBccJLwC2AIzQBudlzhgowAG4I+AZyFqYUZERkcuSUDE3bdUuLK6K1vADYwNcWgG0AuvoC+7dqEixuO0w1NQJiYDpGBFEwO2BRYBRQwhJyVAwcCIZmK04eJC0oXmwYaAAKMF5xOwRsbj5BYTFJKAAaXLl5Kpq6hWVVXidC3XaDTq7q2uFjUx0kIlHxzkrJupt7RyFXNwBKZjhvNkOfNj9oeGR0qjwAQQATTDB0tMpMyJyxuEwHp7KEVFEQkwSAAnjstl4TmcAtggiEwiR7o90u9orF4olHHAkU80C8MjQUll6IxWJ9vsi-gCgaDwQjiR8lnBFDBeFAkNMAO70yJU+IuADkPH4MAFblaiABgr6KnUYol-35AqMIFF4slSvWDjUYp2+jkh2Op3A50CwWS4Rx6QATNR8HBjIk7haSNRgSCSYgYnEEklsT9nhQCRF8KSOhTforAV9aUJ7WSmSy2RyjNyiXzRILhSh5RrMwKZQMdeqo4KVWqFVKBVrHLqvsl9VxDUA)

Comment: The first piece of code accomplished what i needed. Thank you so much!